# How to efficiently/properly store a map of varying classes (all subtypes of a single superclass) for an isometric game?

Tags: c++, game-engine, isometric

For the last few weeks, I've been trying to develop an isometric, tile-based tycoon-style crafting game in my spare time (and really only to see if I am capable) and I have run up against a design challenge that I am struggling with. I have successfully implemented ground tiles and drawing them, et cetera, using a Tile class (held inside a Map class), but I would like to now be able to add objects on top of tiles.

I have been able to create and render objects (like a table) using a fairly clunky debug class, contained within the Map class as a `std::map<int, Object>` and giving Objects X/Y coordinates so the Map can render them in the right places. All of this, while maybe not being the best approach, works, until I try to subclass Objects to give them different functionality.

I had (wrongly) assumed that I would be able to have some sort of heterogenous container for all objects on the map, which I could loop through and run object-type-specific logic during the game loop. I haven't fully scoped out the game yet, so at the moment I was just giving different objects different member variables - such as a container object that has a capacity, a heater object that has an energy rating, and so on. My first test was going to be to be able to place items on the map and then be able to query the sum of, say, all of the capacities of the container objects - just to make sure it works before moving on to the next step.

I've been trying to use open source projects like OpenTTD and some of the Habbo Hotel emulators to figure all of this out, but to no avail. I'd love to hear what others would think the best way to approach this problem would be.

I've experimented with `dynamic_cast`ing and using pointers in my map, but from other answers I've seen, this doesn't seem to be a particularly good way to do it. Should I be creating a pool of objects of the same type and then iterating over each pool during the game loop to keep things more simple?

Comment: Open your C++ book to the chapter that describes how to use "smart pointers" and read it, and store `unique_ptr`s or `shared_ptr`s to your base class, in the map.

Comment: Possibly too broad for SO's Q&A style.  Might be better on one of the game development speciality sites?

Comment: sometimes "efficiently" and "properly" are antonyms..

Comment: "Should" is often a matter of opinion. Pros and cons are more objective. (On the other hand, listing pros and cons for such a non-specific situation is probably too broad for SO.)

Comment: "creating a pool of objects of the same type and then iterating over each pool during the game loop" - note that this kind of game loop design actually has its own advantages and disadvantages. Look up 'entity component system' if you want to broaden your game development horizons a little bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard solution is to store them as pointers of a base class to a concrete object.

If you have

```
class IObject
{
public:
    virtual void render() const = 0;
    virtual ~IObject(){}
};
```

you may do

```
int main()
{
    using IObjectUP = std::unique_ptr<IObject>;
    std::map<int, IObjectUP> m;

    // some concrete objects get created

    for (const auto& [_, o] : m)
        o->render();
}
```

Usage of a `std::unique_ptr` assumes ownership. If someone else owns an object you may use `std::shared_ptr`, `std::weak_ptr`, or `std::reference_wrapper` alternatively.

One more thing. `std::vector` is a default container. If there are no strong reasons for `std::map`, use `std::vector`.

Answer (score 2):

```
std::map<int, std::unique_ptr<Object>>
```

is probably all you need. You should not need `dynamic_cast`s if your `Object` API is clean. e.g. you should be able to use:

```
for(auto x : objects)
{
    x->draw();
    x->simulate();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple options.

The first one is [`std::any`/`boost::any` (before C++17)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any). This is useful if your objects have absolutely nothing in common.

The other option is to use a common interface:

```
class Object {
    public:
       virtual void func() {};

};
```

And inherit from that interface:

```
class A : public Object {
    public:
        void func() {/*my overload*/}
};
```

That way, you can store them in a container like this:

```
Object* obj = new A;
std::map<int, Object*> myMap;

myMap[0] = obj;
```

and get it like this:

```
myMap[0]->func(); // get the overloaded version
```

Of course, you'll need to `delete` `obj` when you're done with it this way:

```
delete obj;
```

It should be noted that this will invalidate `myMap[0]` if it is still set to `obj` when you `delete` it. This is one of the reasons that I wouldn't necessarily recommend doing it this way (`std::any` is much better if you can use it), but it is there if you want to use it.

Of course, you could always use smart pointer instead, as @[Jeffrey has suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57485081/10957435).